# Get most recent date from a column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data which consists out of multiple date entries. I only need to pull the most recent entry. I have tried making use of `ROW_NUMBER()OVER()` but it doesn't help

[image]

Comment: Why didn't `ROW_NUMBER` work? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`

```
row_number() over (order by dt desc)
```

Then filtered it :

```
select t.*
from(select t.*, row_number() over (order by dt desc) as seq
     from table t
    ) t
where seq = 1;
```

If you want separation then include `partition` clause.